# send parameters to bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have number of links that open bootstrap modal popup:

```
<a href="itinPage-secManage.view.php" data-act="edit" data-itinID="5" data-secID="15" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manageSec-model">Edit 15</a>

<a href="itinPage-secManage.view.php" data-act="edit" data-itinID="5" data-secID="32" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manageSec-model">Edit 32</a>
```

the problem - when the modal open it should get the link parameters:

data-act="edit" data-itinID="5" data-secID="15"

Well, it's not happening...

The script in the links page is:

```
<script>
    // send data to modal file
    $('#manageSec-model').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var button = $(e.relatedTarget);

        var act = button.data('act');
        var itinID = button.data('itinid');
        var secID = button.data('secid');
        var date = button.data('date');

        var $modal = $(this);
        var info = 'act=' + act + "&itinID=" + itinID + "&secID=" + secID + "&date=" + date;         
    //  alert(info);

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'itinPage-secManage.view.php',
            data: info,
            success: function(data) {
                $modal.find('.modal-body').html(data);
                setTimeout(function(){ //added this line.
                   setImageUploader()
                })                  
            }
        });     
    }); 

</script>
```

Modal:

```
echo "itinID: ".$_GET['itinID']." secID: ".$_GET['secID'];
```

Result in Modal:

itinID: secID:

itinID: 5 secID: 15

two lines (not sure why...)

Comment: Other than than the fact that the link doesn't have a `date` attribute, it seems to be working just fine. http://jsbin.com/zayodenawi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: not exactly - Modal in on another file that get the url parameters and pull data from the DB. in my case the modal doesn't get the parameters from the links page... @bassxzero

Comment: you're going to have to rewrite that comment in English or I can't help you.

Comment: @bassxzero - sorry : not exactly - My Modal is on another file. it get the url parameters and pull data from the DB. in my case the modal doesn't get the parameters from the links page...

Comment: Are you trying to do this? http://jsbin.com/vivofifake/1/edit?html,js,output    (I added the get parms to the link href attribute.)

Comment: @bassxzero - i tried, but i haven't saw the parameters in the modals...

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? Show the code for `itinPage-secManage.view.php`

Comment: @bassxzero - modal file contain: include_once "global.php";  

echo "itinID: ".$_GET['itinID']." secID: ".$_GET['secID'];

Comment: @bassxzero - I found the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

for this to work you will have to call ajax on click of the anchor tag and for passing the values to ajax you can do following on click of anchor tag

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

or

```
$(this).attr("data-secID");//haven't tried this 2nd one
```

and then launch modal with JavaScript or jQuery with

```
$("#someId").modal();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm sure what you exactly meant...can you please show me some example?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#tblViewBrands").on("click","tbody a",function(){
  manualAjax("viewBrandCnt.php?getUpdateModal="+$(this).attr("id"),"#formUpdateBrand");
  $("#updateBrandModal").modal();
 });
</script>`.......................................................................... where manualAJAX() is call to ajax function and #formUpdateBrand is the ID of element where the result will be appended

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
```

to

```
var button = $(e.target);
```